# Why does Folly's shared library reference the wrong symbol from Boost? (GCC on OS X)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, boost

I'm trying to build & run a small sample application that uses [Folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly) on OS X Yosemite using GCC 4.9.3. Here's the source code:

```
#include <folly/AtomicHashMap.h>

int main() {
    folly::AtomicHashMap<int, int> map(256);
    map.insert(std::make_pair(1, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

I built and installed both Boost (1.59.0) and Folly (latest GitHub head) from sources, making sure GCC was used, and now their libs and headers are available in `/usr/local`. GCC and other dependencies were installed using MacPorts. I can build the above sample successfully using the following command line:

```
$ g++-mp-4.9 main.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lfolly -lglog
```

However, when I try to run it, there's the following error:

```
$ ./a.out
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNK5boost15program_options22error_with_option_name23substitute_placeholdersERKSs
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libfolly.57.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/libfolly.57.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

From what I understand, the way this is supposed to work is that `/usr/local/lib/libfolly.57.dylib` automatically pulls in `libboost_program_options.dylib` by reference at load time. I can see it listed as a dependency when I run `otool -L`:

```
$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/libfolly.57.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libfolly.57.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libfolly.57.dylib (compatibility version 58.0.0, current version 58.0.0)
    libboost_context.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libboost_program_options.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    ...
```

`libboost_program_options.dylib` is located in `/usr/local/lib`, and if I rename it to something else, running `./a.out` causes the loader to complain about not being able to find it instead ("dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_program_options.dylib"). So it seems that the loader is able to find it, at least.

I checked the symbols exported by this library using `nm -gU`:

```
$ nm -gU /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.dylib | grep program_options
    ...
    0000000000023560 T __ZNK5boost15program_options22error_with_option_name23substitute_placeholdersERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE
    ...
```

So there is a symbol very similar to the one that the loader complains is missing. The mangled name just has a different suffix.

[**Edit:** It's not very easy to see the names unless you scroll to the right, so here they are again:

- `nm` says the library contains `__ZNK5boost15program_options22error_with_option_name23substitute_placeholdersERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE`
- The "missing symbol" at load time is `__ZNK5boost15program_options22error_with_option_name23substitute_placeholdersERKSs`.]

I found the corresponding declaration in `/usr/local/include/boost/program_options/errors.hpp`:

```
namespace boost { namespace program_options {
...
    class BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DECL error_with_option_name : public error {
...
    protected:
...
        virtual void substitute_placeholders(const std::string& error_template) const;
```

I presume this is the header file that Folly used when I built it because it's the only matching occurrence of `substitute_placeholders` in all of `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include` and `/opt/local/include`. (Note that Folly doesn't even call this function directly, but it does `#include <boost/program_options.hpp>` from `folly/experimental/ProgramOptions.h` and use other members of `boost::program_options`.)

It seems to me that the longer mangled name -- the only that's actually exported from `libboost_program_options.dylib` -- is the correct one, since it includes the `std::string` argument.

So what could possibly cause `libfolly.57.dylib` to reference a different (shorter) mangled name instead?

Other notes:

- I originally installed Boost from MacPorts instead of building it from sources, and it resulted in the same error.
- If I build the sample using `g++-mp-4.9 main.cpp -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/opt/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libfolly.a -lglog` -- in other words, just link with Folly's static library instead -- the problem goes away, and the sample runs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using c++filt (or http://demangler.com) to demangle the two symbols, the symbol in the boost library has a `std::__1::basic_string` prefix, while the one which is missing in folly has `std::string`. Some googling indicates that the `__1` subnamespace is used by libc++ (clang's C++ standard library) to avoid conflicts with libstdc++ (GNU's). This indicates that boost was compiled using clang and libc++, which is default on OS X, while folly was compiled with libstdc++ (either by using g++ or specifying different flags to clang).

Since the two libraries don't have a compatible ABI, just fixing the symbol name won't help you, so your solution will have to involve recompiling either so that they both are sharing the same standard library implementation.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't actually built Boost using MacPorts GCC like I thought I did. I configured Boost.Build correctly this time and now all is good.